# html table is not accessible on server side. asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an html table inside form view. I made it runat="server" but on server side it is not accessible by id - tblDemandData. my code is-

```
<asp:FormView ID="DemandDataView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="DemandDataDIV" runat="server" visible="true">
            <asp:Button Text="exportBtn" runat="server" ID="btnExport" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
            <hr />
            <div class="headingtext" runat="server" id="tblDiv" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;"><%= LocalString("DemandDataText")%></div>
            <table border="0" runat="server" id="tblDemandData" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="tabletext">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;text-align:right"></td>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("PhaseAText")%></td>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("PhaseBText")%></td>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%= LocalString("PhasecText")%></td>

                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;text-align:right">Total</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("VoltageABText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousVoltagePhaseAB", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("VoltageBCText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousVoltagePhaseBC", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("VoltageCAText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousVoltagePhaseCA", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("VoltageAngleABText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousVoltagePhaseAB", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("VoltageAngleBCText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousVoltagePhaseBC", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("VoltageAngleCAText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousVoltagePhaseCA", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("VoltageHarmonicdistorsionText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousVoltageHarmonicDistortionPhaseA", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousVoltageHarmonicDistortionPhaseB", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousVoltageHarmonicDistortionPhaseC", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("CurrentHarmonicdistorsionText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("IharmPhaseAPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("IharmPhaseBPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%# Eval("IharmPhaseCPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("DistorsionPowerText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousDistorsivePowerPhaseA", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousDistorsivePowerPhaseB", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousDistorsivePowerPhaseC", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousDistorsivePowerThreePhase", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("PowerFactorText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;"></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;"></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;"></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("ActivePowerText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstActiveKWA1", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstActiveKWB1", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%# Eval("InstActiveKWC1", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("instKW", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("ApparentVAText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("VAarithPhaseAPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("VAarithPhaseBPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px; text-align: right"><%# Eval("VAarithPhaseCPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstVArms", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("ApparentVAPFText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("instPFA1", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("instPFB1", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("instPFC1", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("PFinstAVA", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("ReactivePowerText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstVARA1", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstVARB1", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstVARC1", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("ArithmeticVARSysPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("ReactiveVARPFText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("PFinstAVAR", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("PhaseorVAText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("PVAPhaseAPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("PhaseAPVBI", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("PVAPhaseCPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("instVA", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("PhaseorVAPFText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousCosinePhaseA", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousCosinePhaseA", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousCosinePhaseA", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstantaneousCosineThreePhase", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("PhaseorVARText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("VARPhaseAPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("VARPhaseBPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("VARPhaseCPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstVARTimeDelay", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("PhaseorVARPFText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("PFinstPVAR", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("PFAngleText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("PFanglePhaseAPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("PFanglePhaseBPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("PFanglePhaseCPV", "{0:N4}")%></td>   

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("FrequencyText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("InstFREQ", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabletextbold" style="width: 240px;"><%= LocalString("TempratureText") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%# Eval("temperature", "{0:N4}")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 151px;text-align:right"><%= LocalString("NAText") %></td>  

                    <td style="width: 240px;text-align:right">
                        <%= LocalString("NAText")%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

please help me what is wrong I am doing.

Comment: A control contained in a `FormView` cannot be accessed directly from codebehind since it's `NaminContainer` is not the page itself but the `FormViewItem`. So you need to use `FindControl` on that.

Since a `FormView` has multiple modes you have to use it on the right one. The best place to access it is in `FormView.DataBound` with a `switch`-statement on the `FormViewMode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go through `FromView` to access controls in its `ItemTemplate`

```
 HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable)DemandDataView.FindControl("tblDemandData");
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Options Are Available -

Option 1. (Most Recommended) - You may try Html agility pack API to parse the html text.[HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Option 2. Use String Builder make append `<Table>` code to String Builder variable and pass it to html code . Sample is Below -
[Pass Html Table to Aspx With String Builder](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/12/display-data-in-html-table-from-database-using-aspnet-in-csharp-vbnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

As was said, you should use FindControl("YourControlID") on parent control of your table. Notice, what FindControl, can iterate only within first-level child controls, as i remember..

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me,please check this..

Just add `<asp:TemplateField>` on the top of the tag `<itemtemplate>`.